# Database context didn't see any records in datatable in base

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql

I'm creating  an ASP.NET MVC application which uses a PostgreSql database. Model classes are in a different class library. For access to database I'm using Entity Framework + Npgsql.Entityframework in the class library. Also i added same links to main project. Configuration settints are in web.config of main project:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" 
                  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NpgsqlContext" 
         providerName="Npgsql" 
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=BaseId;Password=BasePass;Port=5432;Database=Base;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql"
             support="FF" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

My database context has right connectionn string
(`PORT=5432;KRBSRVNAME=name;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20;COMPATIBLE=2.2.7.0;HOST=127.0.0.1;USER ID=BasePass;PASSWORD=BasePass;DATABASE=Base`),
but didn't see any records in datatable in base. Meanwhile records are there. 
I created database and some tables in pgAdmin. To access to tables i use classes:

```
public class NpgsqlContext : DbContext
    {
        public NpgsqlContext(): base(nameOrConnectionString: "NpgsqlContext") 
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BaseArticle> BaseArticles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ARTICLE", Schema = "public")]
    public class BaseArticle
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("DATETIME")]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        [Column("TITLE")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column("BODY")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

NpgsqlContext object is created normally, but DbSet BaseArticle's count equals 0.

Where can i have an error?

And also - in ASP.NET MVC generally impossible to achieve loose coupling between the parts of the application?

Comment: This connection string is not the same as in your web.config (under NpgsqlContext). Which one do you use?

Comment: Evk, excuse me. I changed database login, pass and name for post. And i did it different ways in config and connection string. When the application runs, they are identical. Connection - Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection

Comment: So you connect successfully but when doing some selects there are no records in database? Do you use code-first or model-first?

Comment: Well I was seeking for a clues, but seems without some more info it will be just pointless guessing, there may be many reasons. Maybe postgresql case-sensivity is a problem? For example you created database using quoted name (like "Base") and then in connection string you use Database=Base (without quoting). Names without quoting are lowercased, to it references to another database. As I said, that's just a wild guess with info provided.

Comment: Yes, it is. Connect is right. I created database and some tables in pgAdmin. Later i created  C# classes to access to tables. NpgsqlContext object is created normally, but list of tables's records is 0. Samples of contex and table code  i added to main post, cause i can't format it to comment.

Comment: Evk, i added some samples to main post. May be it's necessary something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution of my problem i needed to open connection to base in constructor of context:

```
this.Database.Connection.Open();
```